# Perl glob strange behaviour

Tags: perl, glob

I have a piece of perl code:

```
if (glob("$data_dir/*$archivefrom*")) {
    my $command1 = "zip -r -T -m $backup_dir/$archivefrom.zip $data_dir/*$archivefrom*";

    my $err_cmd1 =system("$command1");
    if ($err_cmd1 != 0){print "Error $command1\n";exit 1;}
}
```

sometimes the if returns true but the zip would not match anything, why would that happen? There is no concurrent processes that would remove files in the meantime, it's just glob is returning something different from zip archive match for files, it returns non-empty result even though it should be empty.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the result of the `glob`?

Comment: that was another question - can I do it in one line - print glob results?

Comment: You could do `@files = glob(...)` and then `print join "\n", @files";`.  In one line that becomes `print join "\n", glob(...);`

Comment: I just retested for a date that I had problems with and it returned false in the if statement. So it looks like this changes and it returns different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `glob` function in scalar context becomes an iterator, not a test for file existence! This can be demonstrated by the following code:

```
use feature 'say';
my @patterns = ('{1,2,3}', 'a', 'b', 'c');
for my $pattern (@patterns) {
  my $item = glob $pattern;
  say $item // "<undef>";
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
<undef>
```

That is, `glob` remembers the *first* pattern it was given, then iterates over all matches, but not use any new patterns it was given until the iterator is exhausted. Therefore in your expression `glob("$data_dir/*$archivefrom*")`, updated values in the `$data_dir` and `$archivefrom` variables are not recognized. You will also get one `undef` return value at the end of all possibilities. Then the `if` branch obviously isn't executed.

To test if at least one file matching your pattern exists, you have to fetch all matches at once, thus avoiding the iteration. Use list context for that. We could use the pseudoperator `()=` to count the number of matches – anything ≥ 1 is fine. We can also assign the *first* match to a variable, and use it in your `system` command, to avoid shell interpolation issues:

```
use autodie ':system'; # automatic error handling, additionally requires IPC::System::Simple

if (my ($archivePath) = glob "$data_dir/*$archiveFrom*") {
  system 'zip', '-r', '-T', '-m', "$backup_dir/$archivefrom.zip", $archivePath;
}
```

Comment: From my testing it's not exactly behaving the way you describe - if I have several files matched the if will return true and the zip will archive the files. The next time I call the glob it will match with the new values I pass it. I can see the change though and I'll try it that way to see if it helps, thanks!

Comment: ok, I tested, this only archives the first match, not all the list of files. I would need to pass all the file names to zip command, not just the first match.

Comment: Then: `if(my @archivePaths = glob ...)` and `system ..., @archivePaths;`

Comment: this works, let me change the program and run it for some time. The thing I don't understand is that my initial program worked as well most of the times, but only sometimes it would get incorrect if, i.e. glob would usually be right when there is no matches and only sometimes it would return true when it was supposed to be false. I usually have either empty set or several files per wildcard (wildcard is a date).